# How to set web URL parameters while debugging asp.net locally?

Tags: asp.net

I'm locally debugging a page that runs on our server.
The page normally has ?Parameters.

How do I set those when debugging locally?

Comment: Can you give us more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is append the values to your querystring and then set breakpoints in the code-behind or controller.  For example, if have a page at this url:

- webforms: http://localhost/home.aspx?Parameters=1,2,3
- mvc: http://localhost/home?Parameters=1,2,3

You can access the querystring parameters like this:

```
  var foo = Request.Querystring["Parameters"]
```

Here's [a link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring) with a little more instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If your starting page is to contain querystring parameters, you can specify the page with a querystring value in the Start Options for the project.

[Start Options - Visual Studio 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj4nF.png)

the URL to use as localhost is visible in the project properties
[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9eG.png)